# sifr 3.0 - font styles not showing?

Tags: sifr, sifr3

I have created a .swf as instructed, using three font variants - bold, normal and italic however only the first font variant included in the file actually works - the normal and italic variants just don't display. What is going on here? Anyone else seen this issue?

Looking at the rendered .swf file I can only see one font style included / displayed in the test text, though the swf generated report says all fonts were embedded. Why is this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Flash, font variants "FontName Bold", "FontName Italic" are actually different font families. The bold and italic triggered by the buttons in the Flash UI are the ones mentioned in the documentation. These are also the ones triggered by `<b>`/`<strong>` and `<i>`/`<em>` in the HTML markup.